# Convert Json Date to date

Tags: jquery, json

I have use the below code for converting `JSON Date` to `Original Date`. Below is my Code..

```
    var convertDate = function (jsonDate) {
            var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
            return date.format("mm-dd-yyyy");
       };

alert(convertDate(aData["Date"]));
```

Below error is shown in Firebug.

```
 if (isNaN(date)) throw SyntaxError("invalid date");
```

Any Help...

Comment: What does `aData["Date"]` look like?

Comment: what is yout json date String?\

Comment: `parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)` is wrong unless date is in form of a timestamp.

Comment: aData['Date'] = /Date(1425369600000)/

Answer (score 0):

date parsing works like this:

```
 var dateObject = new Date("12-15-2012 01:23");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
function convertDate(jsonDate) {
    var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
    var parts = /\/Date\((-?\d+)([+-]\d{2})?(\d{2})?.*/.exec(jsonDate);

    if (parts[2] == undefined) 
      parts[2] = 0;

    if (parts[3] == undefined) 
      parts[3] = 0;

    return new Date(+parts[1] + offset + parts[2]*3600000 + parts[3]*60000);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer, but I'm writing it as an example of the kind of thinking you should have gone through.

The error it showed is the line of code where it threw an error. Presumably it's inside a library or something. Evidently it threw because the variable `date` was expected to be a number but wasn't. Judging by its name and expected type (number), `date` must be the argument to the constructor for `Date`, and this part was running inside the call to `new Date`. Conclusion: the script fails because parseInt isn't returning a number. To investigate this: click the error line in Firebug to open the part that fails, set a breakpoint there, run it again, and navigate through the call stack by clicking the tabs along the top of the Firefox window.